# How do I craft command blocks?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I went to my friends house, and he was playing Minecraft on the PC. He showed me a command block, but when I went home and opened Minecraft pocket edition, I went to the crafting table but I could not find any command blocks to craft.

What are command blocks and how do I craft them?

Comment: Pocket Edition is few updates behind and command blocks aren't craftable. They would be OP in survival

Comment: The Minecraft and Minecraft-PE tags are mutually exclusive; your question can't be about both.  You're asking about PE, so I'd recommend removing the minecraft tag, as that's not what your question is about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like Caleb said, command blocks are only on the PC/Mac versions of Minecraft.

You can't craft a command block and can't even obtain them through creative mode. You have to enter this command in order to spawn one in:

```
/give [player] command_block [amount]
```

They basically execute a command when given a redstone signal.

Comment: You can now use them in PE.  See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately Command blocks are not available on the iPad.

[Command blocks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Command_Block) have only been implemented on the PC/Mac version of Minecraft, they are not in the [Pocket Edition](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pocket_Edition) or [Console Edition](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Console_Edition) of the game.

Answer (score 3):

[As of update 1.0.5, they have been added to the native game.](http://minecraftpocketedition.wikia.com/wiki/Command_Block)  They can only be obtained via commands in PE.

> Command Blocks can only be obtained by using Commands. They are not available in the Creative Inventory, and cannot be obtained naturally in Survival Mode.

To obtain them, use this command:

```
/give @p command_block
```

[Additional Wiki source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pocket_Edition_1.0.5#Blocks).

Answer (score 0):

You can get them in PE, but only with a mod. On the PC you can get them by typing `/give @p command_block`

Comment: First of all, can you please learn to format your posts correctly. Also, please don't attach links to websites that are not directly related to the question, as it can be considered spam. I have removed all unnecessary information from your post. Also, could you please edit your answer so it contains a link to the mod you are mentioning .Thanks!