# In the new Minecraft Pocket Edition update, how do I get access to the command blocks?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have tried every command I can think of, but they won't work. Is there a command I should use to get access to all other commands?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I craft command blocks?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/172609/how-do-i-craft-command-blocks)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use any command available on the pocket edition. I found a list of commands [here](https://minecraftpocketedition.wikia.com/wiki/Commands).

Remember that command blocks need to be powered with Redstone before their command will activate, and that the command itself must be syntactically correct.

Answer (score 0):

**[How to Get Command Blocks in Minecraft PE](https://mcpehq.com/faq/get-command-block-minecraft-pe/)**

1. Open Minecraft PE and click the Play button
2. Click the Create New button
3. Click the Generate Random button
4. Set Default Game Mode to Creative
5. Enable Cheats
6. Set any other game options desired and click the Play button.
7. Click the Talk/Speak icon.
8. Type the following command: /give @p command_block